# Заполнение AutoCompleteTextView из файла

Tags: java, android

Заполняю `AutoCompleteTextView` из файла, в котором данные в столбик записаны. Не хочет выводить первый элемент из столбика. Если из ресурса все нормально выводит. Что может быть не так?
Структура файла[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так подключаю файл

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.st);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            arr.add(line);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Так вывожу

```
List<String> arr = getTextFromRaw();
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arr);
autotxt1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Что значит не хочет? Добавьте, что у вас в файле, что вы ожидаете чтобы вывелось и что выводится сейчас.

Comment: @eugeneek в файле слова записаны в столбик Так: Кот Собака Птица. Пытаюсь ввести Кот не хочет выдавать варианты, ввожу собака все нормально меняю местами в файле кот и собака если пытаюсь ввести собака опять не выводи. Как будто не видит первой строки. Точнее не строки а слова.

Comment: @eugeneek может попробовать пустую строку в файле сделать?

Comment: Это скорее всего поможет, но это будет костыль. Лучше разобраться, где у вас ошибка. Добавьте вывод `line` в лог в цикле `while` при считывании файла. Выводится ли там первая строчка? И есть ли она в итоге в листе `arr`? Вообще, если пройти дебагером по шагам, то скорее всего найдёте, где ошибка.

Comment: @eugeneek да надо посмотреть попробовать

Comment: @eugeneek вопрос а как добавить в лог в цикле

Comment: Перед `arr.add(line);` сделать `Log.d("line", line);`

Comment: @eugeneek хмм прочитывает но не хочет выводить и ошибок нет